# IEEEtrans template requires not to use algorithm package?

Tags: algorithms, ieeetran

During the IEEEtrans.tex, there is a comment below package algorithmic saying that

> Do NOT use the algorithm
>   floating environment provided by algorithm.sty (by the same authors) or
>   algorithm2e.sty (by Christophe Fiorio) as IEEE does not use dedicated
>   algorithm float types and packages that provide these will not provide
>   correct IEEE style captions.

How can I make a beautiful box to show the pseudo code while using only  the `algorithmic` package?

Comment: You can download the algorithmic package from here: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/ It contains a .pdf with instructions on how to do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newsavebox{\ieeealgbox}
\newenvironment{boxedalgorithmic}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\ieeealgbox}
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
   \begin{algorithmic}}
  {\end{algorithmic}
   \end{minipage}
   \end{lrbox}\noindent\fbox{\usebox{\ieeealgbox}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedalgorithmic}
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
...
\ENDIF
\ENDWHILE
\end{boxedalgorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for sharing! I still have a problem about the caption. Which part should I modify if I want to reference this box? Could I  write the box part into a Table?

Comment: Update: I find the way of adding the title and caption. Move the box part into a '\begin{table}' and '\end{table}' is OK. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Table, you can use a Figure, in which you can add caption and label.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{boxedalgorithmic}
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
\STATE $y \leftarrow 1$
\IF{$n < 0$}
\STATE $X \leftarrow 1 / x$
\STATE $N \leftarrow -n$
\ELSE
\STATE $X \leftarrow x$
\STATE $N \leftarrow n$
\ENDIF
\WHILE{$N \neq 0$}
\IF{$N$ is even}
\STATE $X \leftarrow X \times X$
\STATE $N \leftarrow N / 2$
\ELSE[$N$ is odd]
\STATE $y \leftarrow y \times X$
\STATE $N \leftarrow N - 1$
\ENDIF
\ENDWHILE
\end{boxedalgorithmic}
\caption{My algorithm}
\label{myalgo}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).