# IEEE Algorithms in figure environment caption should read Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, ieeeconf

I need to write some pseudocode and am using the IEEE template. However, the guidelines say that algorithmic should be contained in a figure environment and that I am not supposed to use the algorithm package [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40228/ieeetrans-template-requires-not-to-use-algorithm-package).

So far no problem just put everything in figure instead.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\item[\textbf{Input:}] some input 
\item[\textbf{Output:}] Some output
\STATE $P \gets 1$
\STATE $X \gets 2$
\STATE \RETURN$X + P$
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Algorithm that does stuff}
\label{MagicalAlg}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that this gives me a caption reading `Fig. 1. Algorithm that does stuff` and I would like it to read `Alg. 1. Algorithm that does stuff` 
and not be numbered with the figures but separately.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: I have found a somewhat ugly workaround: I define a new environment based on the figure environment and rename the `\figurename` to `Alg.`. Then I needed to introduce two more counters, one as a placeholder(`PlaceHolder`) and one for keeping track of the actual numbering of the algorithms(`BestAlgorithm`). Otherwise the it would number algorithms and figure together.

```
\newcounter{BestAlgorithm}
\newcounter{PlaceHolder}

\newenvironment{BestAlgorithm}
{\setcounter{PlaceHolder}{\value{figure}} 
 \setcounter{figure}{\value{BestAlgorithm}}\begin{figure} 
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Alg.} }
{\end{figure} \setcounter{figure}   
{\value{PlaceHolder}} \addtocounter {BestAlgorithm} {1}}
```

After defining this in the beginning of the document, I can use `BestAlgorithm` instead of the `figure` environment.

Is there a nicer way to assign a counter to a new environment?

Comment: How about the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147598/how-to-use-the-algorithm2e-package-with-ieeetran-class)... does this help ?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394825/controlling-text-above-and-below-caption-in-algorithm/394915?r=SearchResults&s=2|37.2893#394915

Comment: So the guidelines say to use the `figure` environment. Why are you changing something that might end up being changed back by them anyway?