# Algorithm not continuing to next page in IEEE Journal

Tags: algorithms, ieeetran, algorithmic, ieee-style

I have a very long algorithm that takes more than a page in a double column format from an IEEE journal template. Instead of continuing to the next page, the algorithm pushes the text towards the bottom of the page.

Please see example below taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40228/ieeetrans-template-requires-not-to-use-algorithm-package). I also tried this [method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55883/algorithm-and-ieeetran). Any advise to handle this issue?

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newsavebox{\ieeealgbox}
\newenvironment{boxedalgorithmic}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\ieeealgbox}
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
   \begin{algorithmic}}
  {\end{algorithmic}
   \end{minipage}
   \end{lrbox}\noindent\fbox{\usebox{\ieeealgbox}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedalgorithmic}
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH

\end{boxedalgorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: fbox, lrbox and minipage all create unbreakable boxes (must go on one page).  framed and tcolorbox can handle mutiple pages/columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses tcolorbox.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newsavebox{\ieeealgbox}
\newenvironment{boxedalgorithmic}
  {\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
   \begin{algorithmic}}%
  {\end{algorithmic}%
   \end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedalgorithmic}
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH
\STATE FFFFYJTFYH

\end{boxedalgorithmic}

\end{document}
```