I want to split the algorithm to other column (in this case, the column of the next page). The format is a 2 page column
My code is:
\State \textbf{Initialize: }$n_{ch,IA} \gets false$, $n_{ch,DA} \gets false$, $reached_{IA} \gets false$, $w_{n_{ch,IA}} \gets false$, $w_{r_{low,IA}} \gets false$, $v_{red,computed} \gets false$ 

\State Unfold a simulation of just IA for $n_{steps}$ and build a dataset $\mathcal{D}_{off}$, collecting $N$ samples $s_n$. \Comment{The dataset is built for offline learning}

\State Learn for an amount of $N_{ep,off}$ epochs \Comment{The GRU learns offline} % @TODO: present the learning algorithm in an external algo?

\For{$n \gets 1$ to $n_{steps}$}
\State $t \gets n \cdot dt$
\State Update virtual points position on the desired path, $(x_d, y_d)$        
       \If{$E_{DA} \le E_{low,DA}$}
            \State $n_{ch,DA} \gets true$ \Comment{DA must go to the charging station}
       \ElsIf{$E_{DA} \ge E_{max}$}
            \State $n_{ch,DA} \gets false$ \Comment{DA performs the task}
       \EndIf

       \State Update $DA$ dynamics

        \State Append new samples to the online dataset $\mathcal{D}_{on}$, collecting $N$ samples $s_n$. \Comment{The dataset is built continuously for online learning}

        \State Append new $E_{IA}$ to $E_{past}$

        \If{$|\mathcal{D}_{on}| \geq N$}
        \State Learn for an amount of $N_{ep,on}$ epochs \Comment{The GRU learns online}
        \EndIf

        \State Empty $preds$ array

        \For{$k \gets 1$ to $K$} \Comment{Unroll GRU to predict $K$ future energy values}
        \State $E_{k+1}\gets GRU(E_{past})$ \Comment{Predict value}
        \State Append $E_{k+1}$ to $E_{past}$\Comment{Store predicted value to be used for the next prediction}
        \State Append $E_{k+1}$ to $preds$ array
        \EndFor

        \If{\textbf{any} value in $preds$ is close to $E_{low,IA}$}
        \State $w_{n_{ch,IA}} \gets true$
        \State $w_{r_{low,IA}} \gets true$
            \If{$w_{n_{ch,IA}}$}
            \State $E_{IA,d} \gets E_{IA}$ \Comment{Save current IA energy value}
            \EndIf
        \EndIf

        \If{\textbf{any} value in $preds$ is close to $E_{ch,IA}$}
        \State $w_{n_{ch,IA}} \gets false$
        \State $w_{r_{low,IA}} \gets false$
        \State $v_{red,computed} \gets false$
        \EndIf

        \State $\Call{Set learning velocity}{n_{ch,DA},w_{n_{ch,IA}}, w_{r_{low,IA}}}$ \Comment{Call defining learning velocity procedure}

       \State $\Call{Set reduced learning velocity}{n_{ch,DA}, w_{n_{ch,IA}},%  
       \newline v_{red,computed},reached_{IA}}$ %
       \newline \Comment{Call defining reduced learning velocity procedure}

       \State $\Call{Select DA learning controller}{n_{ch,IA}, n_{ch,DA},%
       \newline w_{n_{ch,IA}}}$ \Comment{Call select DA learning controller procedure}

       \State Update DA dynamics according to (\ref{eq:double_integrator}).
\EndFor

\Procedure{Set learning velocity}{$n_{ch,DA}, w_{n_{ch,IA}}, w_{r_{low,IA}}$} \Comment{Saving t1 instant and defining going to charging station velocity}
   \If{$n_{ch,DA}$ $\textbf{and}$ $\textbf{not}$ $w_{n_{ch,IA}}$ $\textbf{and}$ $\textbf{not}$ $w_{r_{low,IA}}$}
    \State $t_1 \gets t$ \Comment{Save instant when DA needs charging}
    \State $v_{DA} \gets \sqrt{v_{x,DA}^2 + v_{y,DA}^2}$ \Comment{Set go-to charging station velocity}
    \EndIf
\EndProcedure

\Procedure{Set reduced learning velocity}{$n_{ch,DA}, w_{n_{ch,IA}}, v_{red,computed}$} \Comment{Compute $v_{red}$}
    \If{$n_{ch,DA}$ $\textbf{and}$ $w_{n_{ch,IA}}$ $\textbf{and}$ $\textbf{not}$ $v_{red,computed}$}
    \State $v_{red,computed} \gets true$ \Comment{IA has reached minimum energy threshold}

    \State $t_{IA,d} \gets \frac{E_{IA,d}-E_{low,IA}}{B_{d,IA}}$ % @TODO: which is the right terminology for B_c_dumb?
    
    \State $t_{IA,c} \gets \frac{E_{max}-E_{low,IA}}{B_{c,IA}}$ % @TODO: which is the right terminology for B_c_dumb?

    \State $t_{red} \gets t_{IA,d} + t_{IA,c}$
    
    \If{$E_{DA} < (E_{min} + E_{max})$}
     \State $E_{rem} \gets E_{DA} - (E_{min} + E_{max})$ % @TODO: introduce in problem formulation e_max
    \Else 
     \State $E_{rem} \gets (E_{min} + E_{max}) - E_{DA}$
    \EndIf
    \State Compute $v_{red}$ using (\ref{eq:v_reduced})
   \EndIf
\EndProcedure

\Procedure{Select DA learning controller}{$n_{ch,IA}, n_{ch,DA}, w_{n_{ch,IA}}$}
   \If{$n_{ch,DA}$ \textbf{and} $wncd$} \Comment{If IA and DA needs charging}
    \State $U_{DA} \gets U_{track,DA}$ \Comment{DA keeps tracking with reduced velocity}
   \ElsIf{$n_{ch,DA}$ \textbf{and not} $n_{ch,IA}$}
    \State $U_{DA} \gets U_{cs,DA}$ 
   \ElsIf{$n_{ch,DA}$}
    \State $U_{DA} \gets U_{track,DA}$ 
   \Else
    \State $U_{DA} \gets U_{track, DA}$ 
   \EndIf
\EndProcedure

\end{algorithmic}
}
\end{algorithm}


algotithm is a float and cannot be split.  alcorithmic aparently is breakaable.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578021/algorithm-not-continuing-to-next-page-in-ieee-journal

Welcome! Please, make the example into a compilable one.
